# Visualising MODIS Vegetation layers for a specific country (using R-package MODISttsp)

Tags: r, geospatial, r-raster, r-modis

I am trying to download and visualise the NDVI data in Kenya (and other countries similarly).

For this, I retrieved the bounding box for Kenya using `osmdata` and used this when downloading NDVI data from `MODIStsp`

```
library(osmdata)
library(MODIStsp)

kenya_bb <- osmdata::getbb("Kenya")

MODIStsp(gui             = FALSE,
         out_folder      = "Data",
         out_folder_mod  = "Data",
         selprod         = "Vegetation_Indexes_16Days_1Km (M*D13A2)",
         bbox            =  kenya_bb,
         bandsel         = "NDVI",
         user            = "mstp_test" ,
         password        = "MSTP_test_01",
         start_date      = "2020.06.01", 
         end_date        = "2020.06.15", 
         verbose         = FALSE)
```

Then I simply visualised the downloaded data, but it hasn't seemed to crop out Kenya

```
library(raster)
library(here)
library(ggplot2)

NDVI_raster <- raster(here::here("Data/VI_16Days_1Km_v6/NDVI/MOD13A2_NDVI_2020_161.tif"))

NDVI_df <- as.data.frame(NDVI_raster, xy = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
rownames(NDVI_df) <- c()

ggplot(data = NDVI_df,
       aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = MOD13A2_NDVI_2020_161))
```

Any ideas on how to crop out single countries are appreciated

Comment: were you able to solve it? I have the similar issue and I can't figure out why

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this behaviour is that the default value of argument `spatmeth` is `"tiles"`, so values specified with arguments `start_x`, `end_x`, `start_y` and `end_y` (and, if not explicitly specified, their defaults) are used.

From the function documentation:

> **bbox** numeric(4) Output bounding box (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) in out_proj coordinate system. **Ignored if spatmeth == "tiles"**, Default: NULL

> **spatmeth** character ["tiles" | "bbox" | "file"], indicates how the processing extent is retrieves. if "tiles", use the specified tiles (start_x....). If "file", retrieve extent from spatial file specifies in spafile. If "bbox", use the specified bounding box, **Default: "tiles"**

To use the `kenya_bb` extent you have to:

1. add `spatmeth = "tiles"`;
2. correct `bbox = kenya_bb` to `bbox = as.vector(kenya_bb)`

Moreover, there was a bug affecting this case, recently fixed.
You should also reinstall the package from GitHub:

```r
remotes::install_github("ropensci/MODIStsp")
```