# Using a shapefile with MODIStsp R package

Tags: r, spatial, shapefile, r-modis

I'm trying to use the `MODIStsp` R package to download data for a defined country. For this I downloaded the boundary of Mongolia from [here](https://www.igismap.com/download-free-shapefile-maps/) into my working directory and passed it's path into my `MODIStsp()` function. However, this doesn't seem to download the data within the defined boundary and keeps downloading the initial example

```
spatial_file <- "C:/Users/Zstar/mongolia_administrative_boundaries_national_polygon.shp"

MODIStsp(gui             = FALSE,
         out_folder      = "Data",
         out_folder_mod  = "Data",
         selprod         = "Vegetation_Indexes_16Days_1Km (M*D13A2)",
         spafile         = spatial_file,
         bandsel         = "NDVI", 
         quality_bandsel = "QA_usef", 
         indexes_bandsel = "SR", 
         user            = "mstp_test" ,
         password        = "MSTP_test_01",
         start_date      = "2020.06.01", 
         end_date        = "2020.06.15", 
         verbose         = FALSE)


library(raster)
library(here)
library(ggplot2)

raster <- raster(here("Data/VI_16Days_1Km_v6/NDVI/MOD13A2_NDVI_2020_161.tif"))
df <- as.data.frame(raster, xy = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)

ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = MOD13A2_NDVI_2020_161))
```

[image]

Comment: were you able to solve this? There seems to similar issue for everyone. See this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201309/visualising-modis-vegetation-layers-for-a-specific-country-using-r-package-modi

Answer (score 0):

The default value of argument `spatmeth` is `"tiles"`, so values specified with arguments `start_x`, `end_x`, `start_y` and `end_y` (and, if not explicitly specified, their defaults) are used, unless `spatmeth = "file"` is explicited.

From the function documentation:

> **spatmeth** character ["tiles" | "bbox" | "file"], indicates how the processing extent is retrieves. if "tiles", use the specified tiles (start_x....). If "file", retrieve extent from spatial file specifies in spafile. If "bbox", use the specified bounding box, **Default: "tiles"**

Adding `spatmeth = "file"` to `MODIStsp()` should solve.